# Button opacity causing pixel shift/blur in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button, opacity

I have a simple button:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.button {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0095CD;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
}

.button:active {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

When the button is clicked I'm seeing a slight blurring/shifting of the text to the left in Windows 8 Chrome (40.0.2214.111 m). Other Windows browser seem OK apart from Opera where I can see the same effect but not as pronounced.

I haven't tested this yet on OS X Chrome.

I've added this as a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dgwyer/pen/JoMgRw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the default for backface-visibility is visible. Instead of it being visible, you could hide it.Add this CSS style and check:

```
body{ -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on all Windows browsers, and on OS X Chrome too. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .button:active {
      opacity: 0.8;
      -moz-opacity: 0.8;
      -o-opacity: 0.8;
      -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
      -ms-opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp says that `opacity` don't need a prefix. I'm very interested if this works